# Response redirect with http anchor and parameters result in parameter lost

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to make the user to edit some data, way down in the page, and when he post them allow him to return to the same point on the page. Said point is marked with an ol' good HTMLAnchor:

```
<a name="point_in_page">
```

When the user post the data I fire a response redirect to the same page:

```
Response.Redirect("Tickets.aspx#point_in_page");
```

But it results in lost of parameters. So I try to pass it as Querystring:

```
Response.Redirect("Tickets.aspx#point_in_page?IDTicket=\"" + IDTicket + "\"",false);
```

But I'm unable to recover the parameters with:

```
string IDTicket = Request.QueryString["IDTicket"];
```

Is there any way to do this? (I can recover it if I redirect to the url without the anchor, tough).

Thanks!

Comment: Remove the slash / / from your url

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Re-order your query string and hash component, the query string should come first.

The server will ignore everything after the hash, as it is for client-side use only.

That being said, this should work:

```
Response.Redirect("Tickets.aspx?IDTicket=\"" + IDTicket + "\"#point_in_page",false);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the hash component in your url before the querystring then it will lead an error. SO you need to re-arrange your data i.e. add the querystring values first.

```
Response.Redirect("Tickets.aspx?IDTicket=\"" + IDTicket + "\"#point_in_page",false);
```